# How to get percentage value upto two decimal points in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have written following query to get the count and percentage value for individual user:

```
select a.user_type,a.count,a.count * 100/(select sum(sessions) from user_type) as percentage
from
(select user_type, sum(sessions) as count 
from user_type 
group by user_type
order by user_type)  a,
(select user_type, sum(sessions) as count 
from user_type 
group by user_type
order by user_type)  b
where a.user_type = b.user_type and a.count = b.count
group by a.user_type,a.count
```

The percentage values are coming like 7.35684648. Can someone tell me what changes shall I do to get the % value as per my requirement.

Comment: `round()`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [round function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html).

```
select a.user_type,a.count,round(a.count * 100/(select sum(sessions) from user_type),2) ...
```

This should truncate the percentage value to 2 decimal places.